# How do I fix this error in GridWorld, so that I can make these objects properly?

Tags: object, methods, syntax, gridworld

It has come time that my teacher give all of his students the wonderful world of grids, known as GridWorld. And, in exploring that wonderful world, I get more farking errors than an overloaded robot in an old school cartoon. Why must I get errors with syntax that, to me, make no sense? I'll keep looking, but how could I possibly get the following error. I have my foot on it that it's the same mistake I keep making and then forgetting. I'm not sure what that mistake is. Here is my code:

```
Location loc1 = new Location( 10, 3 );

Location loc2 = loc1.getAdjacentLocation( Location.WEST );

Location loc1.getAdjacentLocation(SOUTH);

Location loc1.getAdjacentLocation(NORTHEAST);

(new Location(2, 5)).getAdjacentLocation(NORTHEAST);

(new Location(2, 5)).getAdjacentLocation(52);

(new Location(2,5)).getAdjacentLocation(0);

System.out.println( "loc1 = " + loc1 );

System.out.println( "loc2 = " + loc2 );
```

And I get this error, which I'm positively sure I make whatever this mistake is often.

```
error "';' expected"
```

Crazy right? Thank you so much. I will be quite thankful of whoever gives me a working solution.

Comment: Yes. It is Java. By the way Blue Ice, nice s/n.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I see wrong is that line 5-7 are not given a variable. It should be:

```
Location loc3 = new Location(2, 5).getAdjacentLocation(NORTHEAST);
Location loc4 = new Location(2, 5).getAdjacentLocation(52);
Location loc5 = new Location(2,5).getAdjacentLocation(0);
```

**EDIT**:
Another thing is when you call a `Direction` by its constant you have to use this format, `Location.NORTH`, so this is what you should have:

```
Location.SOUTH
Location.NORTHEAST
Location.NORTHEAST
```